# Getting a single output from multiple if/else outputs

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to get the line count of a few files in a directory by a script. Up until now I was able to do so with if/else statements but I'm getting an output for each file that is checked.
My goal is to get a single "main" output that:

- If all the outputs are "OK" ->> main output will be "OK"
- If even one of the outputs is "PROBLEM" ->> main output will indicate an error.

```
files=`find /backup/external/logs -type f -daystart -ctime 0 -print | grep csv | grep -v Collateral`
count_files=`echo $files | grep -o " " | wc -l`
count_files=$((count_files+1))

for ((i=1;i<=${count_files}; i++));
do
        file=`echo $files | awk -F " " -v a=$i '{ print $a }'`
        linecount=`(wc -l "$file"| awk '{print $1}')`

        if [ $linecount -gt "1" ]; then
         echo "OK"
        else
         echo "PROBLEM! File $file"
        fi
done
```

And my output is:

```
PROBLEM! File /backup/external/logs/log1_20211214010002.csv
PROBLEM! File /backup/external/logs/log2_20211214010002.csv
OK
PROBLEM! File /backup/external/logs/log4_20211214010002.csv
OK
PROBLEM! File /backup/external/logs/log6_20211214010002.csv
```

Comment: Instead of reporting the problem(s) immediately, I would accumulate the `$(basename "$file")` pieces of the problematic files into an array. If the array afterwards is empty, I would output OK. If it is not empty, I would output PROBLEM, followed with the file list.

Answer (score 1):

Accumulate the problematic files in a variable.

```sh
problems=""
for ((i=1;i<=${count_files}; i++));
do
    file=`echo $files | awk -F " " -v a=$i '{ print $a }'`
    linecount=`(wc -l "$file"| awk '{print $1}')`

    if [ $linecount -le 1 ]; then
        problems+="$file "
    fi
done
if [ "$problems" ] ; then
  echo Problems: "$problems"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to report the csv files whose filenames don't contain "Collateral", which have exactly zero or one line. If so you do not need such a complicated script; this all could be done with a single `find` command:

```
find /backup/external/logs -type f -daystart -ctime 0 \
    -name '*.csv' \! -name '*Collateral*' \
    -exec bash -c '{ read && read || echo "PROBLEM! File $1"; } < "$1"' _ {} \;
```

Comment: @Nejat Wow I didn't think this could get this simpler. As I like to understand this better I will add that I need to accumulate the output to one variable/output and also output OK in case all the files have more than 1 line. In this case isn't it simpler/better to use if/else in this case?

Comment: @NetanelPeretz You can do something like that: `problems=$(find command above)` and then `: ${problems:='No problem'}`. The variable `problems` will contain the files with problems, or the string `No problem` if no problematic file found.